# How to transform a string in a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Indeed I have this code :

```
#include <iostream>

double a(){return 1.23;}
double b(){return 1.21;}

int main(){
std::string function0;
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And what I want is this : if function0 = 'a' I would like to be able to transform the string function0 in the function a but I don't know how to do this. If function0 is equals to b I would like to call the function b.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: `std::map<std::string, std::function<double()>>` might help.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is calling one of the functions depending on the value of the string variable. This is easily achievable.

1. An `if else` construct in the `main()`:

   ```
   if (function0 == "a") {
       foo = a();
   } else if (function0 == "b") {
       foo = b();
   }
   ```
2. Merge the function and modify the result, so it behaves differently depending on the input:

   ```
   double newFunction (string input) {
        double valueForA = 1.23;
        double valueForB = 1.21;

        if (input == "a") {
            return valueForA;
        } else if (input == "b") {
            return valueForB;
        } else {
            //what if it's not "a" nor "b"?
            return 0;
        }
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   double foo = newFunction(function0);
   ```

N.B:

1. Don't neglect the return values of your function, if the returned value is not important use `void` function.
2. Learn to use variables (instead of useless functions). You could have created 2 variables in the main, and that would be it.
3. Visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to get started with C++. Without good references, you'll hate learning it, and that would be sad, or would it?
4. Stop using the book/website you're currently using to learn programming. It's (probably) garbage.

Answer (score -1):

function pointers may help.

```
double (*funcPtr)();
int main() {
  if (function0 == "a")
    funcPtr = &a;
  else 
    funcPtr = &b;

  (*funcPtr)(); //calling a() or b()
}
```

Comment: Considering how he put the tag c++11 and c++14, suggesting `std::function` would have been a better choice.